# Need help in creating validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I need some help in creating validaton rule. the requirements are:
If the value of a field on account is not equal to "Cleared", then the user should not be able to update the Service Appointment status to Dispatched. Both are picklist fields.

I have created this rule:

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Status, "Dispatched"),
NOT(ISNULL(TEXT(Contact.Account.DPLStatus__c))),
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Contact.Account.DPLStatus__c, "Cleared"))
)
)
```

It gives no syntax error but is not working either. I am able to update the status to Dispatched even when the account field is not equal to Cleared.

Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: try NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Contact.Account.DPLStatus__c)))   - instead isnull

Comment: AND(
  ISPICKVAL(
   Contact.Account.DPLStatus__c, "Cleared"
  ),
  NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Contact.Account.DPLStatus__c),
  ISPICKVAL(Status, "Dispatched")
 )

This should work.

Comment: @AyushGoyal With your code, it will give the validation error when DPL status field = Cleared. Should it not be : AND( NOT(ISPICKVAL( Contact.Account.DPLStatus__c, "Cleared" )), NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Contact.Account.DPLStatus__c), ISPICKVAL(Status, "Dispatched") )

Comment: What is the object for this validation rule - Case?